# adding tax_query to $query_string

Tags: loop, query-string

I need to adjust the query in the loop.php by adding tax_queries based on $_REQUEST params. i tried something like this

```
$argsExtended = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'my_tag_slug' ),
            'operator' => 'in',
        ),
    )
);
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $argsExtended );
query_posts( $args );
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: what `$_REQUEST` params are you adjusting the query based on? Can you put a sample url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way of doing this is **WP_Query**

```
$query = new WP_Query(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_tag',
            'slug' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'my_tag_slug' ),
            'operator' => 'in',
        ),
    )
);
```

and you should do the ajax callback like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action(){
//my custom code ...
}
```